# How is the radiative damping different for a uniform lattice of atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, quantum-optics

In page 343 of Loudon's *The Quantum Theory of Light*, he states that scattering of light from a uniform spatial distribution of atoms is inhibited, and radiative damping must vanish as a result.

What does this mean exactly? Is it saying that the absorption linewidth tends to zero for a uniform lattice of atoms (neglecting other broadening processes)? If so, has this ever been observed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but Loudon explains this:

> The derivation given above assumes that all of the light
> removed from the incident beam reappears as scattered radiation. A more general
> form of the optical theorem, not considered here, applies when some of the light is
> removed from the beam by nonradiative processes.

In real solids, some light energy gets transformed into internal energy of the solid (the crystal heats up), and does not appear as scattered light. Consequently, one should expect some absorption even for the dense crystal. The cancellation of radiative damping is not perfect, because space cannot be filled by dipole radiators completely uniformly - atoms have size, and there will be empty regions of space, and field of the crystal acting on any single atom won't be exactly in phase with the primary wave. Thermal motions of the atoms furthermore disrupt the regularity of the lattice, and enhance scattering or absorption.